# How to calculate the expectation and the variance of a stochastic integral with correlated Brownian motions?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Right now I dont know how to find the expectation and the variance for the following stochastic integral:
$$\int_{0}^t B(s) dW(s)$$
where $B(t)$ and $W(t)$ are correlated standard Brownian Motions with $d\langle B, W \rangle_t = \gamma dt$.

Usually, when $B(t)$ and $W(t)$ are independent, we know 
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\int_{0}^t B(s) dW(s)\right) = 0$$ and by Ito's isometry, 
$$Var\left(\int_{0}^t B(s) dW(s)\right) = \mathbb{E}\left(\int_{0}^t B(s) dW(s)\right)^2 = \int_{0}^t \mathbb{E}B(s)^2 ds.$$

Does these results still apply?

Comment: In order to find the expectation note that $\mathbb{E}\left[ \int_0^t B(s)dW(s)\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ \int_0^t W(s)dB(s)\right]$, then use Ito's product formula for the process $B(s)W(s)$, now you will have to employ the correlation. Indeed, the answer will be $0$. To find the variance, as you noticed you use Ito's isometry followed by Fubini's theorem and at the end you compute the integral.